# .htaccess goes to 404 - url rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been using a .htaccess on different server successfully using apache but for some reason I can not get it to work on this new hosting package as I keep getting the "Page not Found" screen with the following message: "The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server". 
Urls in browser look like this:  www.mysite.com/about-us

My code is as follow:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: Does your new hosting provider support mod_rewrite?

Comment: I have added my code inside <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule>. I changed  DirectoryIndex index.php   to   DirectoryIndex index.htm index.php,  and the site now takes me to index.htm. I guess it means that mod-rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Answer:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Your favicon.ico condition may be breaking the match. To negate a pattern, use only `!` instead of negating the lexicographically equal match.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```